# Check if a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why this is not working

I have a radio button Yes or No.
Yes uses "id=statut1"

```
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="statut" id="statut1" value="1"<?php if($statut=='1') echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Actif
</label>
```

At some point, I would like to know if the Yes radio button is selected or not.
I used this

```
console.log($('#statut1'));
if($('#statut1').is('checked')){
    console.log("inside");
}
```

When I look into the log, whatever the checked value is (true or false) I never go inside the condition. I can't understand why this is not working.
I'm doing the same thing with a checkbox and I have no issue.

Looks like is('checked") doesn't work for radio button...but still I found many subjects here saying it's working.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed a colon. Use like this:

```
$('#statut1').is(':checked')
```

Comment: That is colon(:) not semicolon(;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Put colons inside (:)

```
$('#' + id).is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:

Using `onchange` event you can trigger function.

**Vanilla JS:**

---

```js
function myFunction(e) {
 console.log(e.target.checked);
}
```

```html
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="statut" id="statut1" value="1" onchange="myFunction(event);"> Actif
</label>
```

---

jQuery:

---

```js
$('#statut1').on('change', e => {
  console.log(e.target.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="statut" id="statut1" value="1"> Actif
</label>
```

---

**OP's Solution:**

---

`$('#statut1').is(':checked')`